# How to use a high current 2 Second current pulse to actuate a servo - First year Electrical Engineer

Tags: aerospace-engineering, servo, electronics, rocketry, pwm

I am using a dual deployment system controller, an Eggtimer Quark REVC2 which at apogee outputs a high current 2 second pulse. I don't have time to buy a more advanced Eggtimer which outputs proper PWM signals. I want to actuate a servo for a specific amount of time to deploy a mechanism and this is dependent on the Eggtimer and apogee, is there a way I can convert this high current 2 second pulse to PWM? How can i use this current pulse to actuate the servo, are there any other components I could use in-between? Help pls

Comment: You're missing a few details. 1. A link to the Eggtimer datasheet. 2. "Apogee" presumably refers to a rocket's apogee based on the tags. Is that correct? 3. What is "high current"? 4. By "servo" do you mean the miniature servo actuators used in model aircraft? They don't use PWM in the normal sense as the timebase is not fixed. They use pulse duration (1 - 2 ms) control.  By the sound of things you want a circuit which gives a continuous train of pulses of one width when the input signal is low and another when high. You need to specify these parameters. Hit the [Edit] link ...

Comment: `outputs a high current 2 second pulse` ... does it really do that? ... it would make more sense for it to close switch contacts for 2 seconds